# how to declare a class as spring bean with minlength of a field set to 8

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I have this class:

```
class UserValidator {
@size(min = 3)
private int size;
//setters&getters
}
```

To declare this class as spring bean I write the following code:

```
@Configuration
class ConfigClass {
@Bean
UserValidation userVaidation(){
@size(min = 8)
int size;
UserValidation  userValidation = new UserValidation ();
userValidatin.setSize(size);
}
}
```

As the code above  the minlength of the field size is replaced to 8?

Comment: No it is not, nor is it possible.

Answer (score 0):

Is `@Size` applicable on int?

```
@Size
```

The size of the field or property is evaluated and must match the specified boundaries. If the field or property is a String, the size of the string is evaluated. If the field or property is a Collection, the size of the Collection is evaluated. If the field or property is a Map, the size of the Map is evaluated. If the field or property is an array, the size of the array is evaluated. Use one of the optional max or min elements to specify the boundaries.

[Using Bean Validation Constraints](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/tutorial/bean-validation001.htm)